# Mockito-inline throws Stream closed exception on RandomAccesFile

Tags: android, mockito, mockito-inline

I have following lines in my testing code

```
RandomAccessFile mockRAF = mock(RandomAccessFile.class);
when(mockRAF.length()).thenReturn(len);
```

with dependency like this

```
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.8.47"
```

and getting

```
Stream Closed
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.length(Native Method)
    at com.example.examplepackage.enterprise.app.Installation$RealFileAccessor.readInstallationFile(Installation.java:87)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

this error.
I have tried several things but unsuccessfully. Removing mockito-inline is not an option, cause there are a lot of tests mocking final classes.
Is there any possible solution I can try out to make this thing work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason mocking fails is that `RandomAccessFile.length()` is a native method.

mockito-inline cannot mock native methods. See [Mocking final types, enums and final methods](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.1.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final):

> Some methods cannot be mocked
>
> - Package-visible methods of `java.*`
> - `native` methods

The approaches to solve:

- if possible, use one of the interfaces RAF implements in method under test
- wrap RAF with your own class delegating to RAF
- use real RAF in tests, but point it to a temporary file you create in the test